# Embedded Jetty is not delivering my web app

Tags: java, maven, embedded-jetty

Despite the documentation claiming how magically easy it is to get an app running with embedded jetty I have been extremely frustrated and unsuccessful. As far as I can tell, the issue is it's unable to find/load web.xml or to find my webapp dir in the overall jar. The structure of my app is:

```
mexp
    mexp
        mexp.json (properties file)
    mexp-jetty
        JettyWebApp.class (contains my main method)
    mexp-webapp
    (etc.)
```

I have multiple modules but I think those are the important ones w/r/t this problem. I'm using maven-shade plugin to build the jar in the mexp-jetty dir (maybe that's my first mistake).

I am running it (trying to) from the root of the project dir, using:

```
java -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:PermSize=64M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -Xms1G -Xmx1G -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/tmp -jar mexp-jetty/target/mexp-jetty-3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar mexp/mexp.json
```

Here's my main method inside JettyWebApp:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Server server = new Server();
    MBeanContainer mbContainer = new MBeanContainer(ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer());
    server.addBean(mbContainer);

    // parse json input from a json file - demonstrably works fine
    MEXPJsonProps mexpJsonProps = parseJsonInput(args);

    Map<String, Object> httpProps = mexpJsonProps.getHttp();
    HttpConfiguration httpConfiguration = new HttpConfiguration();
    int outputBufferSize = httpProps.get("outputBufferSize") instanceof Double
            ? Double.class.cast(httpProps.get("outputBufferSize")).intValue()
            : (Integer) httpProps.get("outputBufferSize");
    httpConfiguration.setOutputBufferSize(outputBufferSize);

    ServerConnector http = new ServerConnector(server,new HttpConnectionFactory(httpConfiguration));
    int port = httpProps.get("port") instanceof Double
            ? Double.class.cast(httpProps.get("port")).intValue()
            : (Integer) httpProps.get("port");
    http.setPort(port);
    int idleTimeout = httpProps.get("idleTimeout") instanceof Double
            ? Double.class.cast(httpProps.get("idleTimeout")).intValue()
            : (Integer) httpProps.get("idleTimeout");
    http.setIdleTimeout(idleTimeout);

    ServerConnector httpAdmin = new ServerConnector(server,new HttpConnectionFactory(httpConfiguration));
    int adminPort = httpProps.get("adminPort") instanceof Double
            ? Double.class.cast(httpProps.get("adminPort")).intValue()
            : (Integer) httpProps.get("adminPort");
    httpAdmin.setPort(adminPort);
    httpAdmin.setIdleTimeout(idleTimeout);

    // Set the connector
    server.setConnectors(new Connector[] { http, httpAdmin });

    WebAppContext context = new WebAppContext();

    context.setClassLoader(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());

    // web.xml location
    String webXmlLocation = "/WEB-INF/web.xml";
    // webXmlLocation = JettyWebApp.class.getClassLoader().getParent().getResource(webXmlLocation).toString();
    context.setDescriptor(webXmlLocation);

    // resourceBase
    String resourceBase = "../mexp-webapp/src/main/webapp/";
    // resourceBase = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource(resourceBase).toString();
    context.setResourceBase(resourceBase);

    context.setContextPath("/");

    context.setParentLoaderPriority(true);

    // Set the handler
    server.setHandler(context);

    server.start();
    server.join();
}
```

mexp-jetty/pom.xml:

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <createDependencyReducedPom>true</createDependencyReducedPom>
                <filters>
                    <filter>
                        <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </filter>
                </filters>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer" />
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>com.pronto.JettyWebApp</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
                            </transformer>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

In addition to following the recomms at the tutorial (http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Embedding_Jetty) I have done some searches, found some ideas here on StackOverflow and other places, but nothing so far has worked. I read for instance that

```
context.setDescriptor(JettyWebApp.class.getClassLoader().getParent().getResource("/WEB-INF/web.xml").toString());
```

was preferable to just

```
context.setDescriptor("/WEB-INF/web.xml");
```

No joy. I also tried both JettyWebApp.class.getClassLoader() and Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader(), as well as trying the parent of each. Nope.

I'm not sure what to try next. I would greatly appreciate any help. Thanks!

ETA: Here is the dump of System.err. I don't see anything useful in it, but maybe you can.

```
Sep 14, 2014 12:49:36 PM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Log initialized
INFO: Logging initialized @82ms
Sep 14, 2014 12:49:37 PM org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server doStart
INFO: jetty-9.2.z-SNAPSHOT
Sep 14, 2014 12:49:37 PM org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler doStart
INFO: Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@47041bea{/,file:/Volumes/Nimue/Development/pronto/mexp-webapp/src/main/webapp,AVAILABLE}
Sep 14, 2014 12:49:37 PM org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector doStart
INFO: Started ServerConnector@543a2dec{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8080}
Sep 14, 2014 12:49:37 PM org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector doStart
INFO: Started ServerConnector@3227f076{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8081}
Sep 14, 2014 12:49:37 PM org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server doStart
INFO: Started @637ms
org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server@4b11a903 - STARTED
 += qtp1554994663{STARTED,8<=11<=200,i=1,q=0} - STARTED
 |   +- 11 qtp1554994663-11-selector-ServerConnectorManager@7310860e/0 RUNNABLE @ sun.nio.ch.KQueueArrayWrapper.kevent0(Native Method)
 |   +- 12 qtp1554994663-12-selector-ServerConnectorManager@7310860e/1 RUNNABLE @ sun.nio.ch.KQueueArrayWrapper.kevent0(Native Method)
 |   +- 13 qtp1554994663-13-acceptor-0@10f71ff4-ServerConnector@543a2dec{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8080} RUNNABLE @ sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept0(Native Method)
 |   +- 14 qtp1554994663-14-selector-ServerConnectorManager@7529a559/0 RUNNABLE @ sun.nio.ch.KQueueArrayWrapper.kevent0(Native Method)
 |   +- 15 qtp1554994663-15-selector-ServerConnectorManager@7529a559/1 RUNNABLE @ sun.nio.ch.KQueueArrayWrapper.kevent0(Native Method)
 |   +- 16 qtp1554994663-16-selector-ServerConnectorManager@7310860e/2 RUNNABLE @ sun.nio.ch.KQueueArrayWrapper.kevent0(Native Method)
 |   +- 17 qtp1554994663-17-selector-ServerConnectorManager@7529a559/2 RUNNABLE @ sun.nio.ch.KQueueArrayWrapper.kevent0(Native Method)
 |   +- 18 qtp1554994663-18-selector-ServerConnectorManager@7310860e/3 RUNNABLE @ sun.nio.ch.KQueueArrayWrapper.kevent0(Native Method)
 |   +- 20 qtp1554994663-20-selector-ServerConnectorManager@7529a559/3 RUNNABLE @ sun.nio.ch.KQueueArrayWrapper.kevent0(Native Method)
 |   +- 22 qtp1554994663-22-acceptor-0@27ad6dbe-ServerConnector@3227f076{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8081} RUNNABLE @ sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept0(Native Method)
 |   +- 23 qtp1554994663-23 TIMED_WAITING @ sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method) IDLE
 +- org.eclipse.jetty.jmx.MBeanContainer@3ba102ef
 |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler$1@6a0d8573=org.eclipse.jetty.security:context=ROOT,type=securityhandler$1,id=0
 |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ListenerHolder@22d16a1f=org.eclipse.jetty.servlet:context=ROOT,type=listenerholder,id=1
 |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.io.ArrayByteBufferPool@fb8a556=org.eclipse.jetty.io:context=HTTP/1.1@543a2dec,type=arraybytebufferpool,id=0
 |   +- o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@47041bea{/,file:/Volumes/Nimue/Development/pronto/mexp-webapp/src/main/webapp,AVAILABLE}=org.eclipse.jetty.webapp:context=ROOT,type=webappcontext,id=0
 |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector$ServerConnectorManager@7529a559=org.eclipse.jetty.server:context=HTTP/1.1@3227f076,type=serverconnector$serverconnectormanager,id=0
 |   +- default@5c13d641==org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet,0,true=org.eclipse.jetty.servlet:context=ROOT,type=servletholder,name=default,id=0
 |   +- qtp1554994663-13-acceptor-0@10f71ff4-ServerConnector@543a2dec{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8080}=org.eclipse.jetty.server:context=HTTP/1.1@543a2dec,type=abstractconnector$acceptor,id=0
 |   +- HttpConfiguration@603170cc{32768,8192/8192,https://:0,[]}=org.eclipse.jetty.server:context=HTTP/1.1@543a2dec,type=httpconfiguration,id=0
 |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ScheduledExecutorScheduler@523f39f2=org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread:context=HTTP/1.1@543a2dec,type=scheduledexecutorscheduler,id=0
 |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.security.ConstraintSecurityHandler@25bcb56b=org.eclipse.jetty.security:context=ROOT,type=constraintsecurityhandler,id=0
 |   +- ServerConnector@543a2dec{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8080}=org.eclipse.jetty.server:context=HTTP/1.1@543a2dec,type=serverconnector,id=0
 |   +- HttpConnectionFactory@5a73fe03{HTTP/1.1}=org.eclipse.jetty.server:context=HTTP/1.1@3227f076,type=httpconnectionfactory,id=0
 |   +- qtp1554994663-22-acceptor-0@27ad6dbe-ServerConnector@3227f076{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8081}=org.eclipse.jetty.server:context=HTTP/1.1@3227f076,type=abstractconnector$acceptor,id=0
 |   +- jsp@19c47==org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet,0,true=org.eclipse.jetty.servlet:context=ROOT,type=servletholder,name=jsp,id=0
 |   +- HttpConnectionFactory@5ef4f91d{HTTP/1.1}=org.eclipse.jetty.server:context=HTTP/1.1@543a2dec,type=httpconnectionfactory,id=0
 |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.io.ArrayByteBufferPool@bc8ba5=org.eclipse.jetty.io:context=HTTP/1.1@3227f076,type=arraybytebufferpool,id=0
 |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ScheduledExecutorScheduler@5b094702=org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread:context=ROOT,type=scheduledexecutorscheduler,id=0
 |   +- sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:8081]=sun.nio.ch:context=HTTP/1.1@3227f076,type=serversocketchannelimpl,id=0
 |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ScheduledExecutorScheduler@43fa0859=org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread:context=HTTP/1.1@3227f076,type=scheduledexecutorscheduler,id=0
 |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ErrorPageErrorHandler@743ee38c=org.eclipse.jetty.servlet:context=ROOT,type=errorpageerrorhandler,id=0
 |   +- [/]=>default=org.eclipse.jetty.servlet:context=ROOT,type=servletmapping,name=default,id=0
 |   +- ServerConnector@3227f076{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8081}=org.eclipse.jetty.server:context=HTTP/1.1@3227f076,type=serverconnector,id=0
 |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server@4b11a903=org.eclipse.jetty.server:type=server,id=0
 |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler@126b227=org.eclipse.jetty.server.session:context=ROOT,type=sessionhandler,id=0
 |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.HashSessionIdManager@8cb09b6=org.eclipse.jetty.server.session:type=hashsessionidmanager,id=0
 |   +- [*.jsp, *.jspf, *.jspx, *.xsp, *.JSP, *.JSPF, *.JSPX, *.XSP]=>jsp=org.eclipse.jetty.servlet:context=ROOT,type=servletmapping,name=jsp,id=0
 |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.HashSessionManager@120b0058=org.eclipse.jetty.server.session:context=ROOT,type=hashsessionmanager,id=0
 |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler@d385acb=org.eclipse.jetty.servlet:context=ROOT,type=servlethandler,id=0
 |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector$ServerConnectorManager@7310860e=org.eclipse.jetty.server:context=HTTP/1.1@543a2dec,type=serverconnector$serverconnectormanager,id=0
 |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.jmx.MBeanContainer@3ba102ef=org.eclipse.jetty.jmx:type=mbeancontainer,id=0
 |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.security.DefaultAuthenticatorFactory@615d5d35=org.eclipse.jetty.security:context=ROOT,type=defaultauthenticatorfactory,id=0
 |   +- sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:8080]=sun.nio.ch:context=HTTP/1.1@543a2dec,type=serversocketchannelimpl,id=0
 |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ListenerHolder@216c6a89=org.eclipse.jetty.servlet:context=ROOT,type=listenerholder,id=0
 |   +- qtp1554994663{STARTED,8<=11<=200,i=1,q=0}=org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread:type=queuedthreadpool,id=0
 |   +- {}=java.util.concurrent:type=concurrenthashmap,id=0
 += ServerConnector@543a2dec{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8080} - STARTED
 |   +~ org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server@4b11a903 - STARTED
 |   +~ qtp1554994663{STARTED,8<=11<=200,i=1,q=0} - STARTED
 |   += org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ScheduledExecutorScheduler@523f39f2 - STARTED
 |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.io.ArrayByteBufferPool@fb8a556
 |   += HttpConnectionFactory@5ef4f91d{HTTP/1.1} - STARTED
 |   |   +- HttpConfiguration@603170cc{32768,8192/8192,https://:0,[]}
 |   |   +~ org.eclipse.jetty.jmx.MBeanContainer@3ba102ef
 |   += org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector$ServerConnectorManager@7310860e - STARTED
 |   |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager$ManagedSelector@35595365 keys=0 selected=0 id=0
 |   |   |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager$ManagedSelector.select(SelectorManager.java:537)
 |   |   |   +- sun.nio.ch.KQueueSelectorImpl@3e1fc537 keys=0
 |   |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager$ManagedSelector@17ccbdbe keys=0 selected=0 id=1
 |   |   |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager$ManagedSelector.select(SelectorManager.java:537)
 |   |   |   +- sun.nio.ch.KQueueSelectorImpl@4ab118d8 keys=0
 |   |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager$ManagedSelector@30d63337 keys=0 selected=0 id=2
 |   |   |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager$ManagedSelector.select(SelectorManager.java:537)
 |   |   |   +- sun.nio.ch.KQueueSelectorImpl@47a72fc8 keys=0
 |   |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager$ManagedSelector@31321838 keys=0 selected=0 id=3
 |   |       +- org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager$ManagedSelector.select(SelectorManager.java:537)
 |   |       +- sun.nio.ch.KQueueSelectorImpl@6eee1626 keys=0
 |   +~ org.eclipse.jetty.jmx.MBeanContainer@3ba102ef
 |   +- sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:8080]
 |   +- qtp1554994663-13-acceptor-0@10f71ff4-ServerConnector@543a2dec{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8080}
 += ServerConnector@3227f076{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8081} - STARTED
 |   +~ org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server@4b11a903 - STARTED
 |   +~ qtp1554994663{STARTED,8<=11<=200,i=1,q=0} - STARTED
 |   += org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ScheduledExecutorScheduler@43fa0859 - STARTED
 |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.io.ArrayByteBufferPool@bc8ba5
 |   += HttpConnectionFactory@5a73fe03{HTTP/1.1} - STARTED
 |   |   +- HttpConfiguration@603170cc{32768,8192/8192,https://:0,[]}
 |   |   +~ org.eclipse.jetty.jmx.MBeanContainer@3ba102ef
 |   += org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector$ServerConnectorManager@7529a559 - STARTED
 |   |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager$ManagedSelector@50f051af keys=0 selected=0 id=0
 |   |   |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager$ManagedSelector.select(SelectorManager.java:537)
 |   |   |   +- sun.nio.ch.KQueueSelectorImpl@67ae0d02 keys=0
 |   |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager$ManagedSelector@53d8337b keys=0 selected=0 id=1
 |   |   |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager$ManagedSelector.select(SelectorManager.java:537)
 |   |   |   +- sun.nio.ch.KQueueSelectorImpl@2e0baf4c keys=0
 |   |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager$ManagedSelector@121be32 keys=0 selected=0 id=2
 |   |   |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager$ManagedSelector.select(SelectorManager.java:537)
 |   |   |   +- sun.nio.ch.KQueueSelectorImpl@53cd7dc7 keys=0
 |   |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager$ManagedSelector@57fcbecc keys=0 selected=0 id=3
 |   |       +- org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager$ManagedSelector.select(SelectorManager.java:537)
 |   |       +- sun.nio.ch.KQueueSelectorImpl@6244b0f8 keys=0
 |   +~ org.eclipse.jetty.jmx.MBeanContainer@3ba102ef
 |   +- sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:8081]
 |   +- qtp1554994663-22-acceptor-0@27ad6dbe-ServerConnector@3227f076{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8081}
 += o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@47041bea{/,file:/Volumes/Nimue/Development/pronto/mexp-webapp/src/main/webapp,AVAILABLE} - STARTED
 |   += org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler@126b227 - STARTED
 |   |   += org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.HashSessionManager@120b0058 - STARTED
 |   |   |   +~ org.eclipse.jetty.jmx.MBeanContainer@3ba102ef
 |   |   |   += org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ScheduledExecutorScheduler@5b094702 - STARTED
 |   |   |   +~ org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.HashSessionIdManager@8cb09b6 - STARTED
 |   |   |   +~ org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler$1@6a0d8573
 |   |   += org.eclipse.jetty.security.ConstraintSecurityHandler@25bcb56b - STARTED
 |   |   |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.security.DefaultAuthenticatorFactory@615d5d35
 |   |   |   += org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler@d385acb - STARTED
 |   |   |   |   += org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ListenerHolder@216c6a89 - STARTED
 |   |   |   |   += org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ListenerHolder@22d16a1f - STARTED
 |   |   |   |   += default@5c13d641==org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet,0,true - STARTED
 |   |   |   |   |   +- maxCacheSize=256000000
 |   |   |   |   |   +- etags=false
 |   |   |   |   |   +- dirAllowed=true
 |   |   |   |   |   +- gzip=false
 |   |   |   |   |   +- maxCachedFileSize=200000000
 |   |   |   |   |   +- redirectWelcome=false
 |   |   |   |   |   +- acceptRanges=true
 |   |   |   |   |   +- welcomeServlets=false
 |   |   |   |   |   +- aliases=false
 |   |   |   |   |   +- useFileMappedBuffer=true
 |   |   |   |   |   +- maxCachedFiles=2048
 |   |   |   |   += jsp@19c47==org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet,0,true - STARTED
 |   |   |   |   |   +- fork=false
 |   |   |   |   |   +- logVerbosityLevel=DEBUG
 |   |   |   |   |   +- scratchdir=/private/var/folders/75/nvnl8bcd211gmkbw1tk2r35c0000gp/T/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-webapp-_-any-840299613557258711.dir/jsp
 |   |   |   |   |   +- xpoweredBy=false
 |   |   |   |   |   +- compilerSourceVM=1.7
 |   |   |   |   |   +- compilerTargetVM=1.7
 |   |   |   |   |   +- com.sun.appserv.jsp.classpath=/Users/barclayadunn/Library/Java/Extensions/libJNPRAuthKit.jnilib:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_67.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_67.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_67.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_67.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_67.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_67.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/System/Library/Java/Extensions/AppleScriptEngine.jar:/System/Library/Java/Extensions/dns_sd.jar:/System/Library/Java/Extensions/j3daudio.jar:/System/Library/Java/Extensions/j3dcore.jar:/System/Library/Java/Extensions/j3dutils.jar:/System/Library/Java/Extensions/jai_codec.jar:/System/Library/Java/Extensions/jai_core.jar:/System/Library/Java/Extensions/libAppleScriptEngine.jnilib:/System/Library/Java/Extensions/libJ3D.jnilib:/System/Library/Java/Extensions/libJ3DAudio.jnilib:/System/Library/Java/Extensions/libJ3DUtils.jnilib:/System/Library/Java/Extensions/libmlib_jai.jnilib:/System/Library/Java/Extensions/libQTJNative.jnilib:/System/Library/Java/Extensions/mlibwrapper_jai.jar:/System/Library/Java/Extensions/MRJToolkit.jar:/System/Library/Java/Extensions/QTJava.zip:/System/Library/Java/Extensions/vecmath.jar:/usr/lib/java/libjdns_sd.jnilib
 |   |   |   |   +- [/]=>default
 |   |   |   |   +- [*.jsp, *.jspf, *.jspx, *.xsp, *.JSP, *.JSPF, *.JSPX, *.XSP]=>jsp
 |   |   |   |   +~ org.eclipse.jetty.jmx.MBeanContainer@3ba102ef
 |   |   |   +~ org.eclipse.jetty.jmx.MBeanContainer@3ba102ef
 |   |   |   |
 |   |   |   +> null
 |   |   |   +> null
 |   |   |   +> null
 |   |   |   +> []
 |   |   |   +> /={TRACE.omission={RoleInfo[],None}, TRACE={RoleInfo,F,C[],None}}
 |   |   +~ org.eclipse.jetty.jmx.MBeanContainer@3ba102ef
 |   += org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ErrorPageErrorHandler@743ee38c - STARTED
 |   |   +~ org.eclipse.jetty.jmx.MBeanContainer@3ba102ef
 |   +~ org.eclipse.jetty.jmx.MBeanContainer@3ba102ef
 |   |
 |   +> sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@4c0c7539
 |   |   +- file:/Volumes/Nimue/Development/pronto/mexp-jetty/mexp-jetty/target/mexp-jetty-3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
 |   |   +- sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader@45e41830
 |   +> javax.servlet.context.tempdir=/private/var/folders/75/nvnl8bcd211gmkbw1tk2r35c0000gp/T/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-webapp-_-any-840299613557258711.dir
 |   +> org.apache.catalina.jsp_classpath=/Volumes/Nimue/Development/pronto/mexp-jetty/mexp-jetty/target/mexp-jetty-3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
 |   +> org.eclipse.jetty.server.Executor=qtp1554994663{STARTED,8<=11<=200,i=1,q=0}
 +- {}
 +- {}
 +- {}
 += org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.HashSessionIdManager@8cb09b6 - STARTED
 |
 +> sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@4c0c7539
     +- file:/Volumes/Nimue/Development/pronto/mexp-jetty/mexp-jetty/target/mexp-jetty-3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
     +- sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader@45e41830
```

Comment: please add a `server.dump(System.err);` in between the `server.start();` and `server.join();` and include that output in your question.

Comment: The output from your server.dump() shows your WebAppContext is a bare webapp context, essentially an empty web app. no Servlets, no Filters, nothing of note.  only the default servlet, jsp servlet, and a handful of default security components with default configurations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to return to the "war" method. From the [embedded jetty tutorial](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Embedding_Jetty#Setting_a_Web_Application_Context):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    String jetty_home = System.getProperty("jetty.home","..");

    Server server = new Server(8080);

    WebAppContext webapp = new WebAppContext();
    webapp.setContextPath("/");
    webapp.setWar(jetty_home+"/webapps/test.war");
    server.setHandler(webapp);

    server.start();
    server.join();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A `WebAppContext` needs full paths to a valid webapp.

Your entries for `webXmlLocation` and `resourceBase` are automatically invalid.

Also, the fact that you are attempting to point to `src/main/webapp` means you are attempting to point to an incomplete webapp, which doesn't have a `WEB-INF/lib` or `WEB-INF/classes`.

We also see spring in your configuration, the components for spring to wireup itself are often using features of the servlet spec that require the container to find/discover/initialize them.  Seeing as these are not present in your environment, nothing is actually starting.

To run your application using `src/main/webapp` would require a configuration that is not valid for a non-development runtime environment, it might make more sense to test your environment out with a valid webapp directory that is fully fleshed out.

Comment: I had read that the paths needed to be relative to the jar, but fwiw i tried full paths as well with no success.